# EFCore: Добавление данных к существующим в поле

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

Мне нужно добавить строку, которую я получаю от клиента в сообщении к существующим данным в БД. Работаю напрямую, с помощью методов:

```
public Order getLastOrder(int UserID)
{
    Order lastOrder = null;
    using (ApplicationContext db = new ApplicationContext())
    {
        foreach (var item in db.Orders)
        {
            if ((item.Customer == UserID) && (item.States == OrderStates.OnChanging))
            {
                lastOrder = item;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    if (lastOrder != null) return lastOrder;
    else
    {
        throw new Exception("No avialable orders with InChanging state for user: " + UserID);
    }
}
```

и

```
public void SaveOrder(Order order)
{
    using (ApplicationContext db = new ApplicationContext())
    {
        db.Orders.Attach(order);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Добавляю данные к текущей строке так:

```
_orderDataCollector = _ordersRepository.getLastOrder(message.UserId);
_orderDataCollector.Description = string.Format("{0}{1}", _orderDataCollector.Description, ("\n " + message.Text)); 
_ordersRepository.SaveOrder(_orderDataCollector);
```

Проблема в том, что при добавлении данных в Description, они не сохраняются.
Я предполагаю, что проблема в методе SaveOrder(Order order);
**Как это исправить?**

Comment: Бррр, написал ответ и понял, что не о том спрашиваете, а о чём -- непонятно.  Давайте так. Покажите код вашего _orderDataCollector - раз. Во-вторых, что у вас именно не сохраняется? Вы хотите создать новый Order (Attach, Add у контекста) или хотите обновить (Update у контекста)?

Comment: Попробуйте после attach выполнить еще и `db.Orders.Update(order);`

Comment: Мне нужно именно обновить данные путём конкатенации строки, а не добавить.

Comment: `orderDataCollector` - просто сущность. Кода нет, только поля.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Судя по всему, EF Core не понимает, что сущность была изменена. Попробуйте вот так:

```
public void SaveOrder(Order order)
{
    using (ApplicationContext db = new ApplicationContext())
    {
        var entity = db.Orders.Attach(order);

        // помечаем сущность как измененную
        entity.State = EntityState.Modified;

        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: Сегодня уже попробовал вариант с `db.Orders.Update(order);` работает, а посему вопрос. В чём отличия?

Comment: @JohnnyRage, согласно [документации](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbset-1.update?view=efcore-3.1), метод Update может также добавлять сущность, если ее нет в БД и подгружать навигационные свойства. Но в вашем случае, достаточно установки свойства State: `Use State to set the state of only a single entity.`